# MVC Mutilple Tables SQL question. What is the best practice

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If my SQL database have around 10 tables I want to use with asp.net MVC. Is it OK to have a model per table and a controller per table or what is the best practice?

Thanks,
EB

Comment: This is too vague; can you supply more context. Definitely one model per table; one controller per model depends on the context.

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial should get you going in the right direction:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started